# Correct way to use meck with foreach

Tags: erlang, eunit, meck

I am using meck to test my gen_server `mymodule`. In particular I use meck to mock `httpc` following the instructions provided [here](http://labs.mochimedia.com/archive/2011/06/13/meck-eunit-best-practices/).

Here is some code I extracted from my test:

```
do_some_tests_() ->
  {foreach,
   fun start/0,
   fun stop/1,
   [fun do_some_stuff/1,
    fun do_some_other_stuff/1
   ]}.

start() ->
  {ok, _} = mymodule:start_link(),
  meck:new(httpc),
  _Pid = self().

stop(_) ->
  meck:unload(httpc), 
  mymodule:stop().

do_some_stuff(Pid) ->
  %% here i use meck
  meck:expect(httpc, request, 
    fun(post, {_URL, _Header, ContentType, Body}, [], []) ->
        Reply = "Data to send back"
        Pid ! {ok, {{"", 200, ""}, [], Reply}}
    end),
  %% here i do the post request
  mymodule:myfunction(Body),
  receive 
    Any -> 
      [
       ?_assertMatch({ok, {{_, 200, _}, [], _}}, Any), 
       ?_assert(meck:validate(httpc))
      ]
  end.
```

With this code I am able to get the tests running but there are still two things I can't understand:

1) In the results I get something like:

```
mymodule_test:43: do_some_stuff...ok
mymodule_test:43: do_some_stuff...ok
mymodule_test:53: do_some_other_stuff...ok
mymodule_test:53: do_some_other_stuff...ok
```

Is it possible to get only one line for each test instead of two?

2) How can I add a speaking description for each test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `do_some_stuff(Pid)` generates two tests, so it's pretty normal both are checked and displayed.

You can however add a name/description to each generator & test:

```
do_some_tests_() -> 
  {foreach,
  fun start/0,
  fun stop/1,
  [{"Doing some stuff" , fun do_some_stuff/1},
   {"Doing some other stuff" , fun do_some_other_stuff/1}
  ]}.




do_some_stuff(Pid) ->
  %% [code]
  [
   {"Check 200" , ?_assertMatch({ok, {{_, 200, _}, [], _}}, Any)}, 
   {"Check httpc" , ?_assert(meck:validate(httpc))}
  ]
  end.
```

This should display something in the likes of:

```
module 'MyModule'
  Doing Some Stuff
    module:57: do_some_stuff (Check 200)...ok
    module:58: do_some_stuff (Check httpc)...ok
```

In EUnit parlance, these are know as "**titles**":

> **Titles**
>
> Any test or test set T can be annotated with a title, by wrapping it
>   in a pair {Title, T}, where Title is a string. For convenience, any
>   test which is normally represented using a tuple can simply be given a
>   title string as the first element, i.e., writing {"The Title", ...}
>   instead of adding an extra tuple wrapper as in {"The Title", {...}}.

http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/eunit/chapter.html#id61107

Comment: Hello. I can get the single descriptions (e.g., Check 200) but if I try to put the main description (e.g., Doing Some Stuff) I get: undefined
*** bad test descriptor ***